# Missing "/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules"

Tags: networking, server

I recently installed Ubuntu Server 16.04 onto a new hard drive.  I had to install it while connected via USB on a different computer (due to the installer not able to detect a keyboard).  I attached the hard drive via SATA to the new server.  I can now boot and it sees the keyboard.

I however have no network.

I am missing the `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` file.

When I execute `sudo lshw -class network` I get the following;

```
*-network DISABLED
description: Ethernet interface
```

When I execute `ifconfig -a` I get the following;

```
eno1 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 9c:5c:8e:95:44:6d
...
```

Comment: Having somewhat similar problem [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/833388/manual-network-configurations-not-working-ubuntu-16-04) as well.

Answer (score 2):

my copy of that file looks like this :

```
# file was automatically generated by the /lib/udev/write_net_rules
# program, run by the persistent-net-generator.rules rules file.
#
# You can modify it, as long as you keep each rule on a single
# line, and change only the value of the NAME= key.

# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 (r8169) 
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="ur::ma:ca:dd:re:ss", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
```

yours will need adjustment to you mac address and your device but as it says at the top of the file its generated by /lib/udev/write_net_rules

Comment: Hmm, I don't even have a "/lib/udev/write_net_rules" file...
I'm not trying to do anything complicated yet...  All I am trying to do is install a base Ubuntu OS on a new computer.

Comment: it sounds to me like the differences between these two systems might be a bit much or the install has failed elsewhere. I'm sure it would be easier to find another method of keyboard attachment than to debug missing parts of udev.

Comment: @Fosol I have the same issue, no /lib/udev/write_net_rules.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo udevadm trigger --subsystem-match=net --action=add
```

will generate `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`.

Run `udevadm trigger --help` for more options.

Comment: It did not add that file on my 16.04 guest

Comment: Likewise, this did not work for me.  It produced no output.