# Manual network configurations not working Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, 16.04, network-manager, udev, interface

Well I had network manager by Network-Manager. For some reason I have to put the same configuration in `/etc/network/interfcaes`. Here's result of `ifconfig` before changes

```
enp0s17   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:d4:30:fe  
          inet addr:10.1.178.177  Bcast:10.1.178.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::b077:68e:9963:1b54/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:7053 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3514 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:8356545 (8.3 MB)  TX bytes:299049 (299.0 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:251 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:251 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:25485 (25.4 KB)  TX bytes:25485 (25.4 KB)
```

With the same configuration as reference I created a new file `/etc/network/interfaces` as

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp0s1
iface enp0s1 inet static
address 10.1.178.179
netmask 255.255.255.0
getway 10.1.178.1
```

I made a small change in the interface-name. In place of `enp0s17` I tried using `enp0s1` and `enp0s17:1`(virtual interface is where I am heading).

But, I am not able to take this configuration up. I have done,

First, I did `systemctl stop network-manager && systemctl restart networking`.

```
networking.service - Raise network interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /run/systemd/generator/networking.service.d
           └─50-insserv.conf-$network.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2016-10-05 18:17:56 IST; 20min ago
     Docs: man:interfaces(5)
  Process: 15599 ExecStop=/sbin/ifdown -a --read-environment (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 16189 ExecStart=/sbin/ifup -a --read-environment (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 16183 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ "$CONFIGURE_INTERFACES" != "no" ] && [ -n "$(ifquery --read-environment --list   --exclude=lo)" ] &&     
 Main PID: 16189 (code  =exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Oct 05 18:17:56 souvik-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...
Oct 05 18:17:56 souvik-VirtualBox ifup[16189]: Cannot find device "enp0s1"
Oct 05 18:17:56 souvik-VirtualBox ifup[16189]: Failed to bring up enp0s1.
Oct 05 18:17:56 souvik-VirtualBox systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 05 18:17:56 souvik-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
Oct 05 18:17:56 souvik-VirtualBox systemd[1]: networking.service: Unit entered failed state.
Oct 05 18:17:56 souvik-VirtualBox systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Furthermore I tried `ifdown enp0s17 --force` successfully, verified as

```
$ cat /run/network/ifstate
lo=lo
```

followed `ifup enp0s1 --verbose --force`, which results

```
Configuring interface enp0s1=enp0s1 (inet)
/bin/run-parts --exit-on-error --verbose /etc/network/if-pre-up.d
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/ethtool
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wireless-tools
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant
/bin/ip addr add 10.1.178.177/255.255.255.0 broadcast 10.1.178.255    dev enp0s1 label enp0s1
Cannot find device "enp0s1"
Failed to bring up enp0s1.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

After reading through [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/767786/changing-network-interfaces-name-ubuntu-16-04) [andThis](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_configuration#Change_device_name), my problem scope has reduced.
How can resent the network-interface-name assigned by `udev` like from `enp0s17` to `enp0s1` or so ?

And, how can I go ahead adding virtual-network-interfaces aka network-alias, because they will be requiring new names as `enps01:1` or `enp0s1:2` and likewise ?

Additionally I am missing rule files under `/etc/udev/rules.d` and am not able to regenerate it as well. Somewhat similar to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/768064/missing-etc-udev-rules-d-70-persistent-net-rules).

**FURTHERMORE**

A network-alias can be added in GUI using Network Manager like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/442318/how-do-i-add-interface-aliases-using-network-manager-gui). How can this be done in CLI, becuase in Server is not supposed to have GUI.

Comment: Why would you arbitrarily change to `enp0s1`?? Is the result the same with the correct `enp0s17`? You probably also need to set a DNS nameserver address.

Comment: As per my understanding, change in name should not affect network config. Is it not so ? If not, how do I go for adding a virtual-network-interface ? And the above configuration had nameservers, I purposely removed it in the post, but you can trust me the results are same.

Comment: It certainly does affect it: `Cannot find device "enp0s1"` I have no experience with virtual interfaces; sorry.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. Changing the name back to `enp0s17` does work, and I guess `udev` is responsible for managing various device/interface names. I updated the post with regard to your opinion.